# Is it possible to set Buffer pool extension on table having clustered Column Store index in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I created Clustered Column Store index on a table. I want to improve memory performance using buffer pool. Is it possible to set buffer pool on sql server, a table having clustered column Store index in SQL Server 2014? What will be the performance gain after setting buffer on it.

Comment: **http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3156/increasing-buffer-pool-in-sql-server-2014/**      **http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/performance-issues-from-wasted-buffer-pool-memory/**

Comment: You can enable buffer pool extensions but you can't dictate which table(s) use it. Is your clustered columnstore table larger than the available RAM on the system? Is it the largest table on the system? BPE won't out-perform RAM - so if the table will fit in memory this feature is not going to help. And if other tables are larger and/or accessed more frequently, you'll need to make the BPE sufficiently large to include everything, otherwise the columnstore table is unlikely to use BPE very much.